# Filter a list of chats

Tags: angular, filter

I'm writing sort of a chat application using Angular 12 and here's what I want to achieve: I want to make a filter by name for a list of chats but the filter doesn't work properly. I think the problem is in the The findIndex() method but can't know how to fix it. Here's what I have so far:

Typescipt:

```
 filterChats(query: string): void {
    if (!query) {
      this.filteredChats = this.chats;
      return;
    }
    this.filteredChats = this.chats.filter(
      (chat) => chat.members.users?.findIndex((m) =>
      m.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) > -1,
      );
  }
```

HTML:

```
   <mat-form-field
                            
     [floatLabel]="'always'">
      <mat-icon
       matPrefix
       [svgIcon]="'heroicons_solid:search'"></mat-icon>
       <input
         matInput
         [autocomplete]="'off'"
         [placeholder]="'Search or start new chat'"
         (input)="filterChats(searchField.value)"
         #searchField>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity I checked the filtering, but that seems OK.

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <H1> TEST </H1>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of filteredChats">{{ item.topic }}</li>
  </ul>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  chats = [
    {
      topic: 'T1 with Jan and Klaas',
      members: { users: [{ firstName: 'Jan' }, { firstName: 'Klaas' }] },
    },
    {
      topic: 'T2 with Kees and Piet',
      members: { users: [{ firstName: 'Kees' }, { firstName: 'Piet' }] },
    },
    { topic: 'T3 with only Jan', members: { users: [{ firstName: 'Jan' }] } },
  ];

  filteredChats: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filterChats("Jan");
  }

  filterChats(query: string): void {
    if (!query) {
      this.filteredChats = this.chats;
      return;
    }
    this.filteredChats = this.chats.filter(
      (chat) =>
        chat.members.users?.findIndex((m) =>
          m.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
        ) > -1
    );
  }
}
```

As I'm unaware of your structure I created one myself.... If you can share your chats-structure then we can find the issue...

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, I tried your code and it works, I still don't know why it doesn't in my app, the issue is when I type a wrong name or a wrong letter that doesn't exist in the list the filter works in this case and nothing shown up, but the problem is when I type a name or a letter that exists in the list of chats, in this case the filter doesn't work and still get all the chats instead of the filtred chats.

Comment: Maybe it’s your chats structure. Please share it in your post.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand what you mean by chats structure, can you please explain more.

Comment: You reference ```this.chats``` what is it type? Can you share an example of the content?

Comment: i made a console.log() for the filtredChats, this what I got after typing the letter "Y" in the search filed  : – 
0:
      members:
             users: Array(1)
                  0:
                     dateOfBirth: null
                     email: "yahia@gmail.com"
                     firstName: "yahyia"
                     gender: "UNKNOWN"
                     id: "62617f588762fa09e9f5b8c8"
                     lastName: "yahyia"